# Is it possible to split a string across multiple lines in an XML file? If so, how?

Tags: xml, app-config

I've got an XML config file with some really long strings.  Generally, I format my source files, etc. so that they can be read without scrolling.  I'd like to do the same to this config file.

Is there a way to split the string across more than one line?  Hopefully, what I'm asking for is obvious but a picture says a thousand words so, e.g. value, below.

```
<add name="validation"
     type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Integration.WCF.ValidationElement, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Integration.WCF, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

If I break the above string to look like this:

```
<add name="validation"
     type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Integration.WCF.ValidationElement,
     Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Integration.WCF, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

my apps fails with:

"An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.serviceModel/behaviors: Extension element 'validation' cannot be added to this element.  Verify that the extension is registered in the extension collection at system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions.
Parameter name: element "

It seems that it's sensitive to line-breaks in the string.

Comment: I've added clarification of where the problem occurs

Answer (score 38, accepted):

All line breaks are [normalized to spaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#AVNormalize), so just put them on a separate line if the space delimiter can handle arbitrary whitespace.

Comment: Dunno who -1'd this. I can confirm that line breaks are normalized. I use this frequently.

Comment: Note that it doesn't combine/collapse spaces, so if you indent the string it will preserve all the whitespace used for indention.